# My prefixes for my discord bots aren't working anymore

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I used to code discord bots a while back using discord.js, and I wanted to see if they still work (they have before) as I have them saved. I get the bot turned on, but it isn't responding to me when I get it to say something. Can anyone help. (I use VSC and I have tried updating Discord.JS and I had to update Node.js to get the bot turned on).

Here is my code for the bot (I was bored and made a bot that posted a pic of a fish when u asked it to).
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

```
client.once('ready', () => {

console.log('Discord Bot Is On!');
```

});

client.on('message', message =>{

```
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;



const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);

const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();



if(command === 'fish'){
    message.channel.send('Here is a fish', {files: ["fish.png"]});
    } 
   else if (command === 'bluefish'){
    message.channel.send('Here is a blue fish', {files: ["bluefish.png"]});
    }
   else if (command ==='greenfish'){
    message.channel.send('Here is a green fish', {files: ["greenfish.png"]});  
   }
   else if (command ==='orangefish'){
    message.channel.send('Here is a orange fish', {files: ["orangefish.png"]});
   }
   else if (command ==='yellowfish'){
    message.channel.send('Here is a yellow fish', {files: ["yellowfish.png"]});
   }
   else if (command ==='violetfish'){
    message.channel.send('Here is a violet fish', {files: ["violetfish.png"]});
   }
   else if (command ==='indigofish'){
    message.channel.send('Here is a indigo fish', {files: ["indigofish.png"]});
   }
   else if (command ==='redfish'){
    message.channel.send('Here is a red fish', {files: ["redfish.png"]});
   }
```

});

client.login('Token');

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have message content privilege intent turned on.
[image: Discord developer portal, application selected]

Read more about it on the discord developer website: https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412

-- Harvey :)